# How can i make python loop repeating two variables

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to make a loop which repeates two variables, variable1 is the header of database its only a static string as declared and variable2 is retrieving data from database actively.

```
variable1="ID | TEXT | TEXT | TEXT"
variable2=datafromSQLTABLE();

while ():
    print variable1
    print variable2
```

So how can i make this code work so that variable1 and variable2 repeats itself like this :

variable1

variable2

variable1

variable2

the loop should stop when there is no more record on variable2(because it takes data directly from db)

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you want the output of your program to be?

Comment: try enumerate or for i,j in ...

Comment: Do you really want your program to print out the letters "v", "a", "r", "i", "a", "b", "l", and "e"?

Comment: put a condition on your while loop

Comment: [Like this?](https://repl.it/Hvkr/0) I assume probably not. So please show us some **actual output** that you want instead of a description of where the output comes from.

Answer (score 1):

If variable2 is an iterator:

```
variable1="ID | TEXT | TEXT | TEXT"
variable2=datafromSQLTABLE();    

for row in variable2:
    print variable1
    print row
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose how many times to repeat you could try something like:

```
    reps = 2
    a = 0
    while a<reps:
        print(variable1)
        print(row)
    a = 0
```